# Building lxpanel on ubuntu and looking for meeting wireless-tools-devel dependency

Tags: compiling, lxde, lxpanel

I'm posting this hoping someone will benefit from this too.
I've spent a lot of time looking everywhere for solution.

When trying to compile lxpanel it fails on wireless-tools-devel requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `./configure` script shows that `wireless-tools-devel` actually looks for `iwlib.h`. Doing `sudo apt-file search iwlib.h` gives required package.

To compile please install:
`$ sudo apt-get install libiw-dev`